# How to apply different colours for different <a> tags in a set

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm a wee bit stuck...

I'm trying to make these 4 icons different colors
[image]

```
<div class="row centered">
        <div class="row centered">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 w">
                <a  title="Twitter" href="http://twitter.com/itsjaymem" target="_blank" > <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-4x"></i></i></a> 
                <a  title="JimmyP.co" href="http://jimmyp.co" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-code fa-4x"></i></a>
                <a  title="Instagram" href="http://instagram.com/itsjaymem" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-4x"></i></a>
                <a  title="Email Me!" href="mailto:jayme@jimmyp.co"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-4x"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add *individual styles* to each a tag to override the existing.

Comment: Use CSS filter to change colors

Comment: There is a way to select 'n-th child' in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
 .fa-twitter{
    background-color:Red;
 }
 .fa-code{
    background-color:Green;
 }
 .fa-instagram{
    background-color:Yellow;
 }
 .fa-envelope{
    background-color:Blue;
 }
```

**Note**: there is error in your code:

change this

```
<i class="fa fa-twitter fa-4x"></i></i>
```

To

```
<i class="fa fa-twitter fa-4x"></i>
```

Comment: @JimmyP have you got this worked??? I dont think using `background-color:Yellow;` will do the job in `font-awesome`. We need to use `color` instead, they are fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Use `:nth-child` pseudo class like this,

**[FIDDLE DEMO >>](http://jsfiddle.net/84gV8/)**

```
.w a:nth-child(1)
{
    color:#FF0000;
}
.w a:nth-child(2)
{
    color:#FF00FF;
}
.w a:nth-child(3)
{
    color:#CCCCCC;
}
.w a:nth-child(4)
{
    color:#FFFF00;
}
```

Refer to `:nth-child` in detail [HERE >>](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild)

Comment: There are certain browsers like ie8 which does not support nth child. In that case do we have any other solution?

Comment: @Wisam either you can use separate `classes` for each one and assign properties, or use little jquery, like `.eq()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `nth-of-type` to target each or you can use `element[attr=val]` to target those elements uniquely and assign color to them..

If you are going with `nth-of-type` you can write it as

```
div.col-lg-8 a:nth-of-type(1) i {
   color: #f00;
}
```

Or if you are going with `element[attr=val]` selector, you can write it as

```
div.col-lg-8 a[class*="fa-twitter"] i {
   color: #f00;
}
```

---

You can also assign the colors straight away to the respective classes, only if you are going to use it on a single element, than you can write it as...

```
.fa.fa-twitter {
   color: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well one thing that you can try is adding an "id" to those icon tags.

**HTML**

```
<a  title="Twitter" href="http://twitter.com/itsjaymem" target="_blank" > 
<i class="fa fa-twitter fa-4x" id="twitter-icon"></i></i></a>
```

Then on your CSS you would target that "id" and use background-color.

**CSS**

```
#twitter-icon { background-color=blue; }
```

Comment: the code is wrong,its not  ‘ background-
color=blue;‘ its ‘background-
color:blue;‘ you don't use ‘=‘ in style